# How to configure nested path for links in html

Tags: html

I have a page courses which opens on `mydomain.com/courses`. There are multiple courses in that page which I want to open as `mydomain.com/courses/course-1` instead of `mydomain.com/course-1`.
How do I set up hrefs for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using standard filepaths we can use `.` to signify the current directory and `..` to represent the directory if we were to move up a folder, so if we are as `mydomain.com/courses/` then

```
<a href="../courses">Courses</a>
```

would point to the same page, relative to where the page currently is, at least. So in your case trying to get the relative path to `course-1` instead of typing out the entire link, use

```
<a href="./course-1">Course 1</a>
```